# jira-python transitions REST API

Tags: python, jira

I've recently started working with `jira-python` and I noticed that there was a method `jira.transition_issue` that takes in an argument `resolution`. What is `resolution` and why does it have an `id`?

Example:

```
jira.transition_issue(issue, '5', assignee={'name': 'pm_user'}, resolution={'id': '3'})
```

Additionally, for transitions, when I do `jira.transitions(issue)`, I often get

```
[{u'id': u'701',
  u'name': u'Close Issue',...
```

Why does close issue have an `id` of `701`? Isn't closed an id of `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some transitions have a screen that has the resolution field on it. This is treated as a required field so you have to provide it. It's a shame it won't take the name of a resolution, but that's how it is.

Look carefully at the workflow of the issue you're transitioning and you should see at least two different transitions named Close Issue, one with id of 2 and another with an id of 701.